# Host two web application on the same domain using Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, routes

It might be weird, but i need to setup a domain for two different applications, one is built with Symfony3 whereas the other has been made with Wordpress. Both websites are on the same server.

www.example.com -> wordpress

www.example.com/custom-slug -> symfony3

is it possible to achieve this using Apache2 ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: why not set up subdomains? use two vhost entries?

Comment: for SEO purpose i guess, if i had the choice i would have done it, its my boss request.

Comment: Yes it is possible using Virtual Host in Apache2 follow this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Doesnt answer my question unfortunately, but thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you actually tried just doing it the way you've described? Set up wordpress in the root, and then Symphony in a specific directory within the root?  It _should_ work just fine.

Comment: when i read you it looks so obvious to do so, i'm going to try this out

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about managing your servers can be asked on [sf]. In the future, similar questions should be asked there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Alias` directive to map all requests matching the pattern /custom-slug/* to the Symfony app. All other URLs will be served from wordpress.

Sample vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /your_web_root/www_example_com/wordpress/

        # All URLs begining with /custom-slug will be fetched from the symfony app
        Alias "/custom-slug" "/your_web_root/www_example_com/symfonyApp/web/"

        <Directory /your_web_root/www_example_com/wordpress/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /your_web_root/www_example_com/symfonyApp/web/>
                AllowOverride None
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from All

                <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                    Options -MultiViews
                    RewriteEngine On
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
                </IfModule>
           </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: @lmdz60z, coud you please select this answer as the right one, if this configuration worked as expected? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the solution above works perfectly, but it took me a while to figure out so I thought I can share with you my version on Redhat Linux and secure port 443:

create a virtual conf file for it in /etc/httpd/conf.d such as mycustom.conf and inside it write this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.u.com
    ServerAdmin devteam@u.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    # This is your Symfony or second website/application web access location such as: mydomain.u.com/mysymfonywebsite
    Alias "/mysymfonywebsite" "/var/www/SymfonyProject/public/"
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/l.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/l.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/chain.crt
    ErrorLog logs/error.log
    CustomLog logs/access.log combined
    # This is your wordpress or any website you want
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    # This is your Symfony web application configuration continued  
    <Directory /var/www/SymfonyProject/public>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted

            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                    RewriteEngine On
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
            </IfModule>
    </Directory>
```

you have question feel free to ask :) and good luck!

D.